# Do we really need 24GB RAM to install SharePoint 2013 Server?

Tags: installation

Do we really need 24GB to RAM install SharePoint 2013 Server? Can I install this in my 6GB machine, will things work as expected with limited apps activated?

By the way, I am thinking of a single server installation.

Comment: Our office of 20ppl ran one with 8gig and found it slow. 24gig was noticably faster (for us)

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need that much RAM simply to run SP2013. I run SP2013 in a virtual machine with 5.5 GB of RAM. (My host machine has 8 GB total RAM)

My Virtual Machine consists of:

1. Windows Server 2012 64 bit
2. SQL Server 2012 64 bit
3. SharePoint Server 2013

If I don't run any services and simply use base SharePoint 2013 Server on this machine, the average ram consumption is 3.5 to 4 GB. It runs smoothly without freezing at all.

Some notes about my Setup:

1) I have created this machine strictly for evaluation purposes. I do not know how it will perform as a development machine or in production. I have yet to install Visual Studio 2012 on it as the SharePoint tools have not RTMd.

2) I have yet to test the RAM consumption after starting some core services like Search and User Profile.